# 500 error when compressing files with .htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, compression, gzip

I'm trying to compress files with .htaccess but I'm getting a 500 internal error,

This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
# JavaScript compression htaccess ruleset
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
php_value auto_prepend_file gzip-js.php
php_flag zlib.output_compression On
```

I've also tried this but getting the same error,

```
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do you have [`mod_deflate`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_deflate.html) installed?  Try this instead and see if your error goes away.

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
</ifModule>
```

If this resolves the 500 error, then you probably don't have `mod_deflate` installed.  You can test it by visiting [HTTP Compression Test](http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/).

If you have access, you may be able to enable it by uncommenting the following lines in your `httpd.conf` file.

```
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

Then you will need to add an output type for each file type you wish to compress.

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

As mentioned in the comments, `AddOutputFilterByType` depends on [`mod_filter`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_filter.html). If you still get a 500 error you should check that this module is loaded too.

You can read more here: [Use mod_deflate to Compress Web Content delivered by Apache](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/05/10/use-mod_deflate-to-compress-web-content-delivered-by-apache/)

I can't find any documentation that suggests whether Siteground supports `mod_deflate` or not. Their KB suggests using gZip from PHP.

[How to enable gZIP compression for your pages?](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_enable_gZIP_compression_for_your_pages.html)
[How to compress my CSS with gZIP?](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_compress_my_CSS_with_gZIP.html)

Comment: Thanks Nilpo, I'm not getting the error anymore, but I dont see it should get compressed when I try to check if its copmressed, so how can I improve thats really compressed?,

Comment: Actually, if that resolved the error, you do not have the necessary module installed.  You can test compression for a page here: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

Comment: Ok, I test it in two sites, and its not gzipped, so I guess I need to install it?

Comment: @believeme Alternatively you can run `sudo a2enmod deflate` and `sudo service apache2 restart` to load mod deflate

Comment: @Nilpo Thank you very much, lets investigate it, and I'll let you know the results I got.

Comment: @Scott I dont have much knowlage in these two types you mentioned, but just curious to know if I need to instal that things or am I able to do that without installaitions?

Comment: mod_deflate is generally available in most PHP installations.  Who is your hosting provider?

Comment: @Nilpo Siteground.com is my hosting provider

Comment: Thanks alot @Nilpo I very appreciate your help, I'm looking into your post and let you know my results.

Comment: @Nilpo I actauly did these two things you mentioned in the last edit and it works perfectly, but I'm trying to do that in a .htaccess file so I dont have to put the php in each aditional file, so I'll try to figure how to do it with .htaccess what you mentioned in the first edit.

Comment: Unfortunately LoadModule only works within the context of the httpd.conf file.  The reason being that modules are loaded when the Apache service is started, not each time a request is made which is when the .htaccess file is checked.

Comment: @Nilpo I see in the `phpinfo()` file that zip option is enabled, and also zlib is enabled, that means that mod_deflate is also anabled?

Comment: The zip extension adds support for zip files.  The zlib extension is used for PHP compression.  Neither is part of mod_deflate.  The .htaccess check I gave you earlier is the easiest way to determine if it is loaded or not.

Comment: @Nilpo Now I got it, [look at this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6802), the problem is that in some version you have to use `mod_deflate`, and some versions you have to use `mod_gzip`, any ways, I very appreciate your help, I'll check you answer.

Comment: Correct.  I believe in Apache 2.x, mod_deflate is preferred.  Earlier versions use mod_gzip.

Comment: Note to anyone else having problems with this. I had to also enable "mod_filter" in addition to "mod_deflate". Cheers.

Comment: I can confirm that indeed, uncommenting  "mod_filter" can help fix the issue, as that is how I resolved mine.

Comment: I might add that mod_headers needs to be enabled too (magento)

Comment: @Nilpo,I commnet` #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so`,but compression still work.what's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

After spending hours of search I found this [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6802), thought someone else might find it helpful,

Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

> ## DEFLATE ##
>
> #mod_filter.so and mod_deflate.so

should be ON !!!!

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer a bit, because it gives an impression of SCREAMING. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me (paste in `.htaccess`):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```